# Zpool not recognized since moving host

Tags: server, 22.04, raid, zfs

A zpool with 2 HDD in raid 0+1 was running on Ubuntu server (18.04). The computer died and won't turn on anymore, probably a PSU failure.

I've moved the zpool discs into a new machine and the are fine, this host is running a fresh KUbuntu 22.04 install.

It won't recognize the pool. zfs-fuse complained that the formatting was too new although this machine is running a newer Ubuntu release than where the discs came from. zfsutils-linux simply states there is no pool to import.

With zfs-fuse on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
# $ zpool import -a
# cannot import 'NAS': pool is formatted using a newer ZFS version
```

With zfsutils-linux on Ubuntu 22.04:
# $ zpool import -a
# no pools available to import

I have managed to take the boot disk (actually a memory card) out of the old machine, which has Ubuntu server 18.04, and the zpool came online without issue.

Any suggestions as to how to get the pool back online in 22.04 ?

Comment: Where are the pool config files. I bet on the hard drive of the the old dead machine?

Comment: @David ZFS metadata is self-contained on the disks. However, it would be good if you could tell which commands you're trying to run, and also as much as you know about the pool from the old machine (name, disks etc.).

Comment: @Artur Meinild thanks